# JSON Response Key validation using Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

Can we validate JSON response key using [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org)?

Objective is to run a smoke test and ensure JSON objects/key are not changing after every deployment.

Comment: Can you specify in details what you want to check?

Comment: i want to validate the Jason key/object/attributes(count/label) of the response are not changing from build to build.

Comment: sample Jason response:
 { "checked": false,
  "dimensions": {
    "width": 5,
    "height": 10
  },
  "id": 1,
  "name": "A green door",
  "price": 12.5,
  "tags": [
    "home",
    "green"
  ]
}

Want to ensure  count of the response key as : 10 
Key are same as : Checked, dimensions, width, height,…. Tags

Comment: Also, i want to check the label case sensitive

Comment: Hello, Any feedback on answer ? If it's ok , you should accept it and upvote so that it's useful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use :

- [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) under your request which will create keys variable and since you put -1 as match number, it will count number of matches and export keys_matchNr :

> $..*

[image: JSON Extractor]

- Then add an [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) that will assert on keys_matchNr variable:

[image: Response Assertion]

Comment: Thanks. Is  there way to check the order  of the key remains same from build to build?